# Stopping a long-running method using channels

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm working on an example using Go channels and I'm facing an issue. Let's say we have a method that runs for approximately 1 hour. This method performs various operations such as writing to a database, reading data, and sending emails. I want to make this method interruptible from the outside, and I'm trying to achieve this using channels.

The problem I'm encountering is that since no signal is received from <-cancelled, the code inside the default case is being executed. However, the code inside the default case takes 5 seconds to execute, and I'm sending a cancelled signal from the main function at the 2nd second.

Since the code inside the default case continues to execute, it captures the cancelled signal only after the default block is completed.

What we desire is for the code inside the default case to stop immediately if a cancelled signal is received.

Thank you in advance for your help. Have a great day!

```
func worker(cancelled <-chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
        case <-cancelled:
            fmt.Println("Worker cancelled")
            return
        default:
            fmt.Println("Working...")
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("ended")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    cancelled := make(chan struct{})
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker(cancelled, &wg)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        cancelled <- struct{}{}
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Program completed")
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a context and wait for a context cancellation and act on it?

Comment: Don't use `time.Sleep()`, that doesn't monitor your channel. Instead use `time.After()` with a `select` that monitors the channel returned by `time.After()` **and** your channel.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `context.Context` instead of channel. In fact this kind of operation is one of the common patterns to use the `context` package. Context offers the ability to use the same context's Done channel to stop multiple go routines.

```
select {
  case ctx.Done():
    return
  default:
    longRunningFunc(ctx)
}
```

And if `longRunningFunc` does multiple operations then the same context can be passed down and made to listen by all the functions which needs to be stopped immediately on signal.

But if the long running operation is single operation then there's no way to stop that in the middle. In that case it would useful to think whether such an operation should run on a signal or as a default case.

Comment: The long-running method includes multiple jobs, but the most time-consuming place is a single transaction. so context.context can't solve our problem because it can't stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in this case, no matter what you use context.Context or channel, you need to handle the interruptible points by yourself. Check condition before every job starts like below. This gives you flexibility to modify what you want to do after one of jobs done, but others are not executed.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func checkDone(done <-chan struct{}) bool {
    select {
    case <-done:
        fmt.Println("Worker cancelled")
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func worker(cancelled <-chan struct{}, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for {
        if checkDone(cancelled) {
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("Working...")

        // Before important works start, check for cancellation
        if checkDone(cancelled) {
            return
        }

        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

        // this is interruptible point in the middle, check for cancellation
        if checkDone(cancelled) {
            // because previous job is done, 
            // but I receive the done signal, what should I do for this case?
            // write some code
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("ended")
    }
}

func main() {
    cancelled := make(chan struct{})
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker(cancelled, &wg)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        cancelled <- struct{}{}
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Program completed")
}
```